# Calculate all possible combinations of column totals using pyspark.pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have the following code which takes columns in my pandas df and calculates all combination of totals minus duplicates:

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4,5,6,3], 'b': [5,7,1,0,5], 'c':[3,4,2,1,3], 'd':[2,0,1,5,9]})

orig_cols = df.columns
for r in range(2, df.shape[1] + 1):
    for cols in it.combinations(orig_cols, r):
        df["_".join(cols)] = df.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)
        
df
```

Which generates the desired df:

[image]

To take advantage of distributed computing I want to run this same code but using pyspark.pandas.  I convert the df to spark and apply the same code....

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4,5,6,3], 'b': [5,7,1,0,5], 'c':[3,4,2,1,3], 'd':[2,0,1,5,9]})
dfs = ps.from_pandas(df)      # convert from pandas to pyspark

orig_cols = dfs.columns
for r in range(2, dfs.shape[1] + 1):
    for cols in it.combinations(orig_cols, r):
        dfs["_".join(cols)] = dfs.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)
        
dfs
```

but I am getting an error message:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Why is the code not working?  What change do I need to make so it can work in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error fixed by converting `tuple` to `list`. Try this:

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

ps.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4,5,6,3], 'b': [5,7,1,0,5], 'c':[3,4,2,1,3], 'd':[2,0,1,5,9]})
dfs = ps.from_pandas(df)      # convert from pandas to pyspark

orig_cols = dfs.columns
for r in range(2, dfs.shape[1] + 1):
    for cols in it.combinations(orig_cols, r):
        dfs["_".join(list(cols))] = dfs.loc[:, list(cols)].sum(axis=1)
        
dfs
```

Comment: Perfect that works!  Just wondering, (1) why do you add the ps.set_options(...) statement and (2) why do the cols have to be entered as list(cols) in spark but not pandas?

Comment: As I know, there are some differences between `pandas` in `pyspark` and normal ones. Those links give you more detail: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311732/pyspark-equivalence-of-df-loc), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700260/cannot-combine-the-series-or-dataframe-because-it-comes-from-a-different-datafr)